Spring boot : Java tools compilation not working with FatJar
We have a scenario where we are loading the java code as string & compiling it into the class at runtime through javax.tools package . The project is based on spring boot , everything works fine while we run the project from eclipse but we are facing compilation issues with dynamically loaded classes when we run the application as a fat JAR.
The dynamically loaded classes are referring to the packages presents in the dependencies but while running it as FatJar it is not able to find the referred classes.
Error -
public class Rule11 implements Rule {
                               ^
  symbol: class Rule
/com/act21/impaktapps/rule/engine/compiled/Rule11.java:2: error: package com.act21.impaktapps.rule.engine does not exist
import com.act21.impaktapps.rule.engine.*;
^
/com/act21/impaktapps/rule/engine/compiled/Rule11.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
Commons.createInstanceFromInMemoryClassLoader("com.act21.impaktapps.rule.engine.compiled.Rule12",Rule.class).execute(fact);
                                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   class Rule
  location: class com.act21.impaktapps.rule.engine.compiled.Rule11
/com/act21/impaktapps/rule/engine/compiled/Rule11.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
Commons.createInstanceFromInMemoryClassLoader("com.act21.impaktapps.rule.engine.compiled.Rule12",Rule.class).execute(fact);
^
  symbol:   variable Commons
  location: class com.act21.impaktapps.rule.engine.compiled.Rule11
/com/act21/impaktapps/rule/engine/compiled/Rule11.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
return (Commons.convert("200004115025",String.class).equals(Commons.getProperty(fact,"pol_agent_code",String.class)));

Rule & Commons classes are part of maven dependency & available in class path.
Compiler Code -
public static Class<?> compile(String qualifiedClassName, String sourceCode)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();

        List<JavaFileObject> sourceFiles = Collections
                .singletonList(new JavaSourceFromString(qualifiedClassName, sourceCode));

        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, manager, diagnostics, null, null, sourceFiles);

        boolean result = task.call();

        if (!result) {
            diagnostics.getDiagnostics().forEach(d -> System.out.println(String.valueOf(d)));
        } else {
            return getClass(qualifiedClassName);
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public static Class<?> getClass(String fqn) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = manager.getClassLoader(null);
        return  classLoader.loadClass(fqn);
    }
    

}

Not sure why this issue is happening while running the project as Jar.It might be related the way spring boot handle the class path but could not figure out any clean solution to solve the issue.
